# Perl dispatches to other interpreters based on shebang line?

Tags: perl, shebang

My mind was blown when I accidentally ran a bash script using perl and it... worked. Experimenting further, it seems perl reads a script's shebang and dispatches to the correct interpreter:

```
$ cat /tmp/ohhai.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo ohhai bash

$ perl /tmp/ohhai.sh
ohhai bash
```

---

```
$ cat /tmp/ohhai.py
#!/usr/bin/python2
print 'ohhai python'

$ perl /tmp/ohhai.py
ohhai python
```

---

```
$ cat /tmp/ohhai.groovy
#!/usr/bin/groovy
println 'ohhai groovy'

$ perl /tmp/ohhai.groovy
ohhai groovy
```

um... wut?

To make sure I'm not crazy, I tried doing this with other interpreters and confirmed this is just a perl-ism:

```
$ python /tmp/ohhai.sh
  File "/tmp/ohhai.sh", line 2
    echo ohhai bash
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

```
$ ruby /tmp/ohhai.sh
ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

---

```
$ bash /tmp/ohhai.py
/tmp/ohhai.py: line 2: print: command not found
```

Is this documented somewhere?  Is it a new thing/old thing? ... Why?

"Swiss-Army chainsaw" indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an old thing documented in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#DESCRIPTION):

> If the `#!` line does not contain the word "perl" nor the word "indir" the program named after the `#!` is executed instead of the Perl interpreter. This is slightly bizarre, but it helps people on machines that don't do `#!`, because they can tell a program that their SHELL is */usr/bin/perl*, and Perl will then dispatch the program to the correct interpreter for them.